# Comparing two array objects data and merge as one object into array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

my arrays :

```
const create = [{"month":"Jan","createCount":"4"},{"month":"Feb","createCount":"5"}];

const close = [{"month":"Jan","closeCount":"3"},{"month":"Feb","closeCount":"5"}];
```

I need to merge the arrays objects to comparing **month** field.

I want my **result** like this...

```
const data = [{"month":"Jan","createCount":"4","closeCount":"3"},{"month":"Feb","createCount":"5","closeCount":"5"}];
```

I **tried** this code:

```
const data = [...create, ...close];
```

but this as merge the two array data only.

please give any solution to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.map()` and `Object.assign()` methods:

```js
const create = [{"month":"Jan","createCount":"4"}, {"month":"Feb","createCount":"5"}],
      close = [{"month":"Jan","closeCount":"3"}, {"month":"Feb","closeCount":"5"}];

const result = create.map(
    o => Object.assign({}, o, close.find(({month}) => month === o.month))
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: In my opinion - Using find within map function is going to hit the performance

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal May be but it depends on the data in arrays also.

Comment: Irrespective of the data, performance will be less. However, smaller data set will have less impact may be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there will be no such entry in `create` array that does not exists in `close` array and vice-versa

Try following using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce),  [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const create = [{"month":"Jan","createCount":"4"},{"month":"Feb","createCount":"5"}];

const close = [{"month":"Jan","closeCount":"3"},{"month":"Feb","closeCount":"5"}];

// Create an object with key as month and createCount as value
let obj = create.reduce((a, o) => Object.assign(a, {[o.month]: o.createCount}), {});

// Iterate over close array and add createCount from obj
let result = close.map(o => ({...o, createCount : obj[o.month]}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply using for in

```
const create = [{ "month": "Jan", "createCount": "4" }, { "month": "Feb", "createCount": "5" }];
const close = [{ "month": "Jan", "closeCount": "3" }, { "month": "Feb", "closeCount": "5" }];
for (var i in create) {
    var item = create[i];
    item.closeCount = close.find(x => x.month == item.month).closeCount;
}
console.log(create);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added some Sample please refer that code

```js
const create = [{"month":"Jan","createCount":"4"},{"month":"Feb","createCount":"5"}];
const close = [{"month":"Jan","closeCount":"3"},{"month":"Feb","closeCount":"5"}];
console.log(create.length);

    for(var data = 0 ; data < create.length ; data++){ 
    var datas = []
    if(create[data].month == close[data].month){ 
        datas=Object.assign(create[data],close[data]);console.log(create[data]);
    }
}
```